# How to install matplotlib 3.2.x on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: matplotlib, installation

Tried several methods to install matplotlib on Ubuntu 16.04, but failed miserably. First I ran 
`sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib`, it always installed `matplotlib 1.5.1` and I wanted the latest version 3.2.1. So I purged it and ran `pip3 install matplotlib` and what I got was always the following error

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-hse72gvy/matplotlib/setup.py", line 139
    raise IOError(f"Failed to download jquery-ui.  Please download "
                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

which seems to suggest that I must install jQuery-UI. I haven't found any working solutions on the internet. Any more has a tip or solution?

Comment: The fact that you get a syntax error here means that you are running python 2, not python 3. Matplotlib 3.x requires python 3.6 or higher.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Actually, I have python3.5 and 3.7 installed on the system.

Comment: Since you still invoke pip via `pip3`, probably `python` is Python 2. And `python` is what's invoked apparently: `Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:`. You could confirm by running `python --version`.

Comment: Actually, you can also get the error with python 3.5, due to the fact that f-strings are used. As said, matplotlib 3.x will require python 3.6 or higher.

Comment: @tsj The ```python --version``` prints 3.5.2.

Comment: There you go. Make sure `python` links to 3.7. Ubuntu will have documentation on that. Or you can try to install with `pip3.7`.

Comment: @tsj. Thanks but ```pip3 install matplotlib``` still complains about the missing juqery-ui. What is the right command?

Comment: Not `pip3`, `pip3.7`. Or, as I said, consult Ubuntu documentation on updating `python` to point to `python3.7`.